# Refresh parent page after Greybox close

Tags: javascript, asp.net, greybox

First of all, merry christmas to all of you :)

I have a blog, where people can make comments. I've now decided to put the "writecomments.aspx" file in a Greybox popup-window. It works, but I want to close the window from codebehind (or javascript) after the comment is written. And then I want to refresh the blog page (the parent page) to show the new comment.

This is the code that opens the greybox (writecomments.aspx) page:

```
<a href='WriteComments.aspx?BlogId=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id") %>' rel="gb_page_center[500, 500]">Skriv kommentar</a>
```

In the writecomments.aspx file, I just have 2 textboxes and 1 button (save-button). 
How can I make the greybox window close itself, and then somehow refresh the blog.aspx? Or maybe just a specific updatepanel for the current comments?

**Edit**
I got it working, I had to put this code in the codebehind, after the db-insert: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "parent.parent.GB_hide();", true);`
And for the refresh of the parent page, I edited the gb_scripts.js file on line 12 from false to true: `this.reload_on_close=true;`

Merry Christmas! :)

**EDIT AGAIN**
Actually, I modified it a bit, so, I put the gb_scripts.js file back to it's default state, and I just just the followig line of code in the WriteComments.aspx codebehind file, just after the db-insert:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "parent.parent.window.location.reload();parent.parent.GB_hide();", true);
```

Now, the Greybox is closing, and then, the blog page is refreshing, just like I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the close function working! This is the code i had to use: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "parent.parent.GB_hide();", true); Now I'll only have to refresh the parent page some way :)

Answer (score 1):

As I am looking for a similar behavior, this is working in my case:
http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=235378.0

"Pleas go through this file (gb_scripts.js)
at line number 12 
change 'this.reload_on_close=false;' to 'this.reload_on_close=true'
and line number 67
change 'window.location.reload();' to 'window.location.reload(true);'
and done
« Last Edit: December 20, 2010, 04:38:42 AM by shashidharkumar »"

Answer (score 0):

Once the comment is successfully saved to DB, render the following javascript in the page:

```
window.opener.reload();
window.close();
```

In your WriteComments.aspx.cs once the save is successful add the code below to render the javascript in the HTML:

```
if (!IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("CloseMe"))
{
        String cstext1 = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
            "window.opener.refresh(); window.close();</" + "script>";
        RegisterStartupScript("CloseMe", cstext1 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm a novice on javascript..how can I "run" this from the codebehind, after the succesful db-insert?

Comment: Updated the previous post with a sample.

Comment: Thanks! But now, when the save button is clicked, it just writes the text "CloseMe" beside the button..

Comment: My bad, swapped the parameters earlier, please try the updated one.

Comment: In the Chrome console it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reload' of null
(anonymous function).

Comment: Now i get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'refresh' of null
(anonymous function)

Comment: Let me have a coffee and try it out before I comment any further :)

Comment: Hey! I got the close function working! This is the code i had to use: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "parent.parent.GB_hide();", true); Now I'll only have to refresh the parent page some way :)

Comment: And now I got this working as well! :) For the refresh, i had to go to line 12 in the gb_scripts.js and edit from false to true (this.reload_on_close=true;)

Comment: Yes :) Thanks for the effort, enjoy your coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

[This is how we do it in JS only.](http://codeofaninja.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-refresh-greybox-parent-page.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the well explained **ANSWER** with easy steps :* http://www.codeofaninja.com/2010/12/how-to-refresh-greybox-parent-page.html